# Chrome on iPhone overflows content on empty page (on new tab only, not reload)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, chrome-ios

On IOS Chrome, the body overflows on a new tab or page with no content, but if the page is reloaded, the problem is fixed. It poses a problem for any element positioned at the bottom (absolute or fixed). Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <style>* {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         html{
          height:100%;
         }
         body {
          height:100%;
          background-color:yellow;
          margin:0 0;
          border: 30px solid red;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

The border should be shown all around the viewport but is being hidden behind the bottom Nav bar. Here is the result from the code above:

[image: New page / tab on Mobile chrome]

[image: After page reload]

Things I have tried (none of them worked):

- Removing "width=device-width" as described here:
  [Empty HTML5 page still overflows and trigger scroll bars on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195740/empty-html5-page-still-overflows-and-trigger-scroll-bars-on-mobile).
- Reload the page with JS. The problem is fixed when a user refresh the page by hand,not programmatically.
- Using transform to zoom in and out to force a refresh

I have tried for a week to find a workaround but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: My issue is different from [HTML body not filling complete width on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358630/html-body-not-filling-complete-width-on-mobile-devices) as I don't have an issue with filling the body, I have an overflowing body issue and mobile chrome behaving differently on a new page as opposed to an existing page. The workarounds on the page didn't work for my issue

My question is the following: Can somebody find a way using css or JS for the HTML body to not overflow when a new page is opened using the code above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML body not filling complete width on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358630/html-body-not-filling-complete-width-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried the workarounds on the post but they do not work

Comment: Do you see any issue with other browsers?  It seems like a bug at first glance.

Comment: This happens only on Chrome. Yes, it is probably a bug, as other websites are affected. I am trying to find a workaround

Comment: how can i reproduce the issue, i put your code on my site and open it on my apple phone with google chrome and i cant reproduce?

Comment: Create link to the page on your site with a target _blank attribute . The page needs to be loaded on a new tab

Comment: Sadly, I can not reproduce such issue on an android phone. Tried running on PC simulating mobile AND an actual android phone but I could not reproduce such issue. Included the target="_blank" from one page to the page with the code you provided and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying. The issue seems to be only on IOS devices. Updating the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem and might have found a solution. I've found [this](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/09/28/avoid-100vh-on-mobile-web.html) which I think causes your problem:

> [...] The core issue is that mobile browsers (I’m looking at you, Chrome and
> Safari) have a “helpful” feature where the address bar is sometimes
> visible and sometimes hidden, changing the visible size of the
> viewport. Rather than adjusting the height of 100vh to be the visible
> portion of the screen as the viewport height changes, these browsers
> instead have 100vh set to the height of the browser with address the
> address bar hidden. The result is that the bottom portion of the
> screen will be cut off when the address bar is visible, thus defeating
> the purpose of 100vh to begin with.

The article suggests that

> One way to get around this issue is to rely on javascript instead of
> css. When the page loads, setting the height to window.innerHeight
> will correctly set the height to the visible portion of the window. If
> the address bar is visible, then window.innerHeight will be the height
> of the full screen. If the address bar is hidden, then
> window.innerHeight will be the height of just the visible portion of
> the screen, as you’d expect.

In the comments they suggested to store the inner height in a CSS variable, refresh it every time the event `resize` or `orientationchange` is fired and apply it to the html and body tags. In my tests that worked only partially. Accessing the page from a link with `target="_blank"` worked fine, but refreshing or directly accessing the page would show the problem you described while accessing the page through a link. To fix that, I'm also updating the variable during the `load` event. On my iPhone 6s and the latest Chrome App accessing the page by link or directly seem to work fine now. I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
      }

      body {
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 0 0;
        border: 30px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body></body>

  <script>
    function fixHeight() {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${window.innerHeight / 100}px`);
    };

    addEventListener('load', fixHeight);
    addEventListener('resize', fixHeight);
    addEventListener('orientationchange', fixHeight);
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, that works like a charm! I was seriously losing hope

Answer (score 1):

WebKit handles 100% height a little strangely, you'll want to use a vendor prefixed property for WebKit devices:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/)

Comment: I tried that, it is didn't work when the page is loaded on a new tab or page

Comment: Did you remove your `height: 100%` from `body` and `html`? Can you describe how it failed to work?

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.fquiz.co/debug but open it on a new tab on Mobile Google Chrome. it is using your answer. You will get the first image on my question

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iOS device to test with, I'm just going off of what has worked before. Hopefully your debug page can help someone with an iOS device to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is the duplication for the same question things are problem will be same just asking method is different.

This is the same question previously asked and also details in right answer explained well.

[CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

This will help you to understand what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my issue is different. I don't have an issue with 100vh and the issue discussed is solved using a script or min-height: -webkit-fill-available. My issue is only on IOS Chrome and only when a page loaded on a tab, not when the page is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found regarding absolute positioning - within Chrome on iOS it appears the `window.innerHeight` initialises with the fullscreen height, then switches to height between the address bar and bottom toolbar shortly after (approx 100ms or so). In my case was `667px` and `553px` respectively.

If you programatically pass the `window.innerHeight` into the height of the parent element of the app to make the height of the app the same as the inner height, as well as giving the top element `position: relative;`, all children of this element with the styling `position: absolute;` will have their position relative to this parent element, NOT the webpage.

It doesn't solve the issue of having the excess height below the content, but it solves the absolute positioning.

HTH.